# Facebook app domain name when using localhost

Tags: facebook

From a tutorial here:
http://ankurm.com/blog/api/using-localhost-for-facebook-app-development/1091/

I tried to set up a Local development Area for my Facebook app. But when I put "http://localhost:85/my_app/" as my domain name, Facebook says

> App Domains: "http://localhost:85/app-name/" should not contain protocol information.

Also when I put "localhost:85/my_app/" as my domain name, I get the error:

> App Domains: localhost:85/my_app/ is not a valid domain.

Comment: I don't believe what you want to update is the "App Domain" instead what you want to update is the "Site URL" located at: Apps > Edit App > Settings > Basic > Website with Facebook Login. Make sure it's checked green and the "Site URL" will appear. You can enter http:// localhost - no need to specify a port, but you most specify the protocol.

Comment: Couldn't get localhost to work under App Domain.  Set  Advanced Settings|'Valid OAuth redirect URIs' to the localhost url (http:// localhost:port#). See https://github.com/tschellenbach/Django-facebook/issues/376

Comment: Also note, app domain must be `localhost` for it to accept the domain.  I tried with mysite.local and it wouldn't work.  Changed `Site URL to http://localhost:85/` and `App Domains to http://localhost:85/` then saved (FB modified App Domain) for it to work.

Comment: Something else to try: "Under Client oAuth settings, where it says Use Strict Mode for Redirect URIs make sure it’s set to No and the hit save." -- https://wp-native-articles.com/blog/news/how-to-fix-facebook-apps-error-cant-load-url-domain-url-isnt-included-apps-domains/

Comment: Requiring HTTPS for Facebook Login. You will still be able to use HTTP with “localhost” addresses, but only while your app is still in development mode.
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/06/08/enforce-https-facebook-login/

Comment: There is a 2018 answer for this! https://stackoverflow.com/a/46658295/1572330
Unfortunately not enough up-votes yet to be on top!

Answer (score 58):

My solution:

1. Leave App Domains empty
2. (Products) Facebook login > Settings
3. Add `http://localhost:85/my_app/` to `Valid OAuth redirect URIs` box
4. Save Changes

Comment: @Matt Long: I didnt find the Valid OAuth redirect URIs box has it been removed?

Comment: @MattLong thanks! I got it working by using Supasates solution.

Comment: Worked for me! (February 2018)

Comment: 10/18/2020 I get this warning "http://localhost redirects are automatically allowed while in development mode only and do not need to be added here."

Answer (score 58):

It seems like the protocol has been changed.

Here is my solution (I tested on 3rd April 2015 and it works well):

In **Settings** -> **Basic** tab

1. **App Domain:** localhost
2. Click "**+Add Platform**" and choose "**Website**"
3. **Site URL:** http://localhost:<port>/ (*<port>* is your port number)
4. **Save Changes**

Comment: does not work, http://s32.postimg.org/4qazo1sl1/Screen_Shot_2016_05_14_at_17_53_03.png

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me (May 2016). Notice, 127.0.0.1 does not work.

Comment: Worked for me June 2017

Comment: Works! December 2017

Comment: Worked! Feb 2021

Answer (score 45):

1. Leave App Domains empty
2. Go to Website with Facebook Login
3. Add `http://localhost:port_number/`
4. Save changes and try again.
   For more information visit

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/samples/canvas/
Happy coding :-)

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/getting-started/ - probably more relevant

Comment: Couldn't get localhost to work under App Domain.  Set  Advanced settings|'Valid OAuth redirect URIs' to the localhost url (http:// localhost:port#). See https://github.com/tschellenbach/Django-facebook/issues/376

Comment: What does mean "Website with Facebook Login" ? An option beside "App Domains" ? I don't see it. Adding the localhost entry in "Advanced settings | Valid OAuth redirect URIs" worked for me

Comment: Did it, still getting error: "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration"

Comment: Working OK. I want just to comment that this only works with 'localhost' as in the answer. I tried with http://127.0.0.1:8000 and did not work

Answer (score 31):

This has changed some over the years, but I just got it to work with a webapp that I'm running on localhost.  This is what I did:

1. Goto https://developers.facebook.com/apps
2. Select your app.
3. Select Settings > Basic from the left hand nav bar.
4. Click the Add Platform button at the bottom of the page.
5. Click Website
6. Enter `http://localhost:8080/` for the Site URL.
7. Click the Quickstart button to the far right of the Site URL you just entered.
8. A new tab will open.  On that tab, scroll down to the section, "Tell us about your website" and again enter `http://localhost:8080/` for the Site URL.
9. Click the Next button.
10. Attempted to login again, and it worked this time.

Good luck!

Comment: there is a way to use two domains? localhost and the domain used for production :/

Comment: Not Working: Still stuck at, URL blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not white-listed in the app's client OAuth settings. Make sure that the client and web OAuth logins are on and add all your app domains as valid OAuth redirect URIs.

Answer (score 29):

**2018 working solution**

It took me ages to figure this out, so I'm going to share my solution.

I tried all the suggested answers, but nothing worked for me, and in the end all I had to do was to go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR_APP_ID/fb-login/settings/, and add my full callback url in the *Valid OAuth redirect URIs* box.

In my case, using ruby on rails, my url looked like this `http://localhost:3000/user/auth/facebook/callback`.

And right after I added it, everything started working! Hope this helps someone else facing this issue.

Comment: Thank you! Surprisingly, you have perfect workable solution for the current moment! Cheers.

Comment: yes thank you.  This worked for me.  I added http://localhost:5001 to section:  *Valid OAuth redirect URIs* and enabled: *Embedded Browser OAuth Login*

Comment: This also worked for me. This is the current working solution. I created a test version of my app for Facebook Login from localhost. (Until Facebook changes things again!)

Comment: Thank you! PITA. After I added that, this notice popped up. **In March, we're making a security update to your app settings that will invalidate calls from URIs not listed in the Valid OAuth redirect URIs field below.This update comes in response to malicious activity we saw on our platform, and we want to protect your app or website by requiring a new strict mode for redirect URIs**

Kinda seems they started early?

Comment: Thanks! It took me ages as well (till I found this answer). Problems is that the error you get from FB suggest you should add your domain to "the app's domains" Which has nothing to do with the actual problem. Thanks for wasting my time again FB :(

Comment: As of 2019 This no longer will work, since facebook is enforcing HTTPS

Answer (score 11):

This is what I used to do.

If you are using Windows, you need to modify the host file. Host file location will be at `%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\`

Add a new line in host file like this

```
127.0.0.1    localhost.YOUR-SITE-NAME.com
```

Save the host file.

Go to FB apps setting control panel and give `localhost.YOUR-SITE-NAME.com` in Apps domain field. Save changes.

Now load you local environment like `localhost.YOUR-SITE-NAME.com` from your browser.

NB: change YOUR-SITE-NAME with your domain name.

Answer (score 7):

**Working solution (August 2018)**

First, select your app in the [developers dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps).

Then make sure your app is in [development mode](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/managing-development-cycle/#step1), as it allows localhost over HTTP. To do so, click on the toggle situated at the top right of your app's page.

Finally, please follow the notes below as they could cause trouble if improperly filled:

- `Settings > Basic > App Domains` should be empty
- `Products > Facebook Login > Settings > Valid OAuth Redirect URIs` should be empty

Comment: is it still working ? i get white label error if i put my app on development mode.

Comment: I have a test-app version of my productive app (always in development mode), cleared all the fields, but still get the error: OAuthException URI missmatch

Comment: When your app is in development mode you can't test any endpoints that require you to submit your app

Comment: Thanks bro, yeash this was tough to finally figure out

Answer (score 5):

You can either leave it blank or use `localhost`, `http://localhost:85/my_app/` is the URL

Comment: yeah i know its the url, but dats wot was done in the tutorial, and he claims it worked...that was why i tried it...by the way i have  also tried localhost:85 but it ddnt work, but when i tried localhost only it worked...The reason  i wanted to use :85 is because that's the port my apache is using...

Comment: The port is protocol information, you don't need it for that field. As the message says: *should not contain protocol information.*

Comment: leaving it blank did the trick. And one more thing it does not accept `localhost` as domain name.

Answer (score 3):

When I wrote that tutorial at that time port was allowed in app domain. And I actually able to run app with 81 port (wamp server). Now it looks that facebook is not allowing port in url. You can use `localhost` in app domain. 
 
I will update information as soon as possible. I am trying to find out solution.

A temporary solution is use localtunnel http://progrium.com/localtunnel/

Answer (score 3):

I tested this and it works for me [Feb 2020]:

1. Install ngrok & get your https url (example: https://a3asdf23.ngrok.io)
2. Go to FB App Dashboard Settings (Basic) -> under App Domains -> add `https://a3asdf23.ngrok.io`, `https://ngrok.io`.
3. On the same page, scroll all the way down, Add Platform (Website), set the url as `https://a3asdf23.ngrok.io`. Not finish yet, click QuickStart -> under "Tell us about your website", put the same url `https://a3asdf23.ngrok.io`.
4. Then go to Products -> Facebook Login -> Settings -> Client OAuth Settings ->  Valid OAuth Redirect URIs -> add these `https://a3asdf23.ngrok.io`, `https://ngrok.io`, `https://a3asdf23.ngrok.io/{your-redirect-uri}`.

And here you go. Thanks me later :)

Comment: This is ridiculous. Facebook should have a easier way to do this. Localhost is a standard and we should click a box and that's it. Waste of our time.

Answer (score 1):

You must create a tunnel to share your localhost;
[Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) is maby the easiest way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

https://ngrok.com

Go through https://ngrok.com/ link to download ngrok and extract that file.
Open cmd ( search cmd)
Go to directory where ngrok is extracted.
Open ngrok from command line ex: c:/ngrok/ngrok.exe [port]  or cd c:/ngrok then ngrok 80 ( ngrok [port] )
You will get

ngrok

```
Tunnel Status                 online
Version                       1.3/1.3
Forwarding                    http://3ahsdfhska.ngrok.com -> 127.0.0.1:80
Forwarding                    https://3ahsdfhska.ngrok.com -> 127.0.0.1:80
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040
# Conn                        0
Avg Conn Time                 0.00ms
```

Don’t FORGET to make sure your wamp server is open on same port … 
(how to check -> goto->wampicon->apache->httpd.conf search for port or 80(default) use that for ngrok.exe 80  )

> `http://3ahsdfhska.ngrok.com`

will be URL for accessing your localhost online

Comment: I would like to test ngrok to fowd to my servlet. My servlet runs on a specific path. FOr example:
localhost:8080/plugins/servlet
How can I instruct ngrok to fwd there?

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the solutions mentioned here but none of them worked.

What solved my issue was copying the "OAuth redirect URI" from firebase to facebook app "Valid OAuth Redirect URIs"

I left all the domains blank

Comment: Can confirm this is the only thing working in january 2021.

Comment: Have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the protocol errors, not only do you need to REMOVE the Http:// but also if there is any backslash at the end of the web address, you  must remove that too or it won't work. I did this and it worked perfectly! Holla!

Answer (score 0):

Tossing one more solution into the mix:

I set up my website per the instructions, then added a second app (Facebook Canvas) and set that URL to `http://localhost:XXXXX`.  Now I can access FB both locally and in production.

Answer (score 0):

I develop locally and I use this URL: `localhost/fb`

Then I had to add a website with the following URL: `http://localhost`

Under *App Domains* I added `localhost`.

Now it works. The only issue I had was, that you have to use this URL in all of your scripts. E.g.

```
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://localhost/fb/login-callback.php', $permissions);
```

You can't use `127.0.0.1` here ...