# Has anyone actually got ASP.NET MVC 5 Identity Facebook logins to work out of the box? (loginInfo always returns null)

Tags: facebook, oauth, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

Using Visual Studio 2013 Update 5, I have created a boilerplate MVC 5 application with Individual User Accounts auth option selected, and I have been trying to implement social logins using the template code, but have been unsuccessful.

I have ensured all NuGet packages are up to date, and the code is using MVC 5.2.3; Owin 3.0.1; AspNet.Identity 2.0.0.

I can get everything working fine, including authenticator apps using OtpSharp, but the Facebook login is just not working whatever I try.

I have created the Facebook App, set all the relevant options on that and set the AppId and AppSecret in my Startup.Auth.cs file.

When I try to login with Facebook, the MVC site redirects me to Facebook, which prompts me with the auth screen for the app. I click OK and accept this then I am redirected back to the MVC app. If I check the authorised apps under my Facebook account, my app is listed and shows that it has granted permission to the app to retrieve email address.

The callback works fine but when it hits `ExternalLoginCallback` and in particular:

```
var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()
```

`loginInfo` always returns null.

Looking at the Request it shows an error of `access_denied`:

```
https://localhost:44301/Account/ExternalLoginCallback?ReturnUrl=%2Fmanage&error=access_denied
```

I have read pretty much every blog post and SO question on this error and whilst most of them are helpful, most are also out of date and not relevant.

It would seem that something is missing from the templated project, or something has changed elsewhere as no matter which tutorial I read, and options I set, the result is the same.

I have tried this internally on a dev machine running IIS Express and externally on a hosted machine running IIS 7.5 too and the results are the same.

I've even decompiled the Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook library to see where that particular section of the querystring is set to no help.

If I had any hair I'd have pulled it all out by now.

I'll take any suggestions. Can anyone help?

Comment: looking over this again, I see you are using localhost... I never had a testing environment setup directly on my workstation, but check to see if your config matches the config mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376710/facebook-app-domain-name-when-using-localhost

Comment: Yep, checked that. I had nothing in App Domains, but putting in `localhost` results in the same. Makes no difference.

Comment: @IraRainey Are you sure you know how to handle async requests? Probably you are printing the log message immediately instead of using a callback function.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely hitting the callback function.

Comment: @IraRainey Set the Valid OAuth redirect URIs in your FB app as http://localhost:1234/signin-facebook. This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook loves to make things difficult. Access_denied sounds like they are blocking you on purpose. Check your developer dashboard and the accounts authorized to test your app while its in development mode. The email permission is approved by default, so that isn't your issue.

Make sure the account you are testing with is added here:

[image: facebook dashboard roles example]

If that doesnt solve it, make sure you have the correct app domains (testing and live) listed in the domain section here:

[image: without the domain here, it will think someone else is trying to jack your app]

Comment: Thanks Kyle, I have checked that and I am the admin of the app with the same email address I am testing it with. I have also tried making the app public and testing it then with the same results.

Comment: added more to my answer. The reason I am not dealing directly with the code you supplied is because 9 out of 10 issues I had when I created my app was not a code issue, it was a development dashboard configuration issue.

Comment: Thanks kind of what I've been thinking, particularly as the Facebook config has changed so much. But all the options I've tried result in the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue. No matter what I did the facebook would show the login, get permissions and then return back to the Login page instead of the Email confirmation page.

Using Fiddler Facebook would invoke "http://localhost:1234/signin-facebook&code=*SOME_SECRET_CODE_HERE*", and then my application's controller would invoke "http://localhost:1234/ExternalLoginCallback?error=access_denied". I was sure Facebook is refusing the access. It was only after implementing a Facebook Javascript SDK Sample, I realised I could successfully login and also view FB scopes!

> ***My Dev environment***
>
> - MVC 5 application
> - Visual Studio 2013 Community edition Update 5
> - Microsoft.OWIN v2.2.1
> - Microsoft.OWIN.Security.Facebook v3.0.1

Finally I found a [YouTube Video by **ProCoder**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6JbYwoD3n3Y) which mentioned to put the correct path in the **Valid OAuth redirect URIs** as **http://localhost:1234/signin-facebook** and it worked. If you haven't already added, you will need to add *Facebook Login* product to your Facebook app.

I also set App Domain to **localhost** and Site URL to **http://localhost:1234/**

I have added **127.0.0.1** and *MY.EXTERNAL.PUBLIC.IP* to the **Server IP Whitelist** Under **Security** in the *Advanced Settings* option of the Facebook app.

All these settings I replicated in a new MVC 5 application and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try when I next look at that section.

Comment: unfortunately these steps do not work for me, I am still receiving null logininfo

Comment: @Nathan is your devenv same as mine? Possibly fb updated their OAuth implementation.

Comment: I was getting a 504 bad gateway error when attempting to get the owin nuget package. I rebooted, and was able to get the latest version of the package

Answer (score 1):

update the package Owin.Security.Facebook 3.0.1 to 3.1.0

It works for me