# How to get posts from facebook page using javascript or php

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-graph-api

I want post from my facebook page, can anyone please tell me the steps to do it? I see the solutions in web but can't getting what to do, can anyone help me to do this? I just have this code.

```
<html>
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<p><a href="#" onClick="logInWithFacebook()">Log In with the JavaScript SDK</a></p>

<script>
logInWithFacebook = function() {
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
    alert('You are logged in &amp; cookie set!');
    // Now you can redirect the user or do an AJAX request to
    // a PHP script that grabs the signed request from the cookie.
  } else {
    alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
  }
 });
 return false;
 };
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 FB.init({
  appId: 'my-app-key',
  cookie: true, // This is important, it's not enabled by default
  version: 'v2.2'
 });
};


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "I just have this working code" Are you sure?

Comment: Error for this is "Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings."

Comment: So your code _isn't_ working then. You should fix that mistake in your question.

Comment: ok, what is the problem can anyone tell me?

Comment: google for the error. you are not the first one with that one.

Comment: about "how to get posts from a page", please start reading the docs. there is example code for every api.

Answer (score 0):

In your application you have inserted wrong domain details. Check your settings.

> 1. Select the correct App and click in the edit button;
> 2. Check the URLs & paths are correctly entered and are pointing to the site where you have installed Ultimate Facebook plugin.

Comment: I am currently coding in local, not in live site, so which URL i have to register on facebook apps?

Comment: You can add localhost with port. refere [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376710/facebook-app-domain-name-when-using-localhost) for the same.